# Setting up CodePipeline template to deploy CloudFormation stack from CodeCommit

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

From a CloudFormation template, you can deploy [CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codecommit-repository.html) and [CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html). From [this announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/aws-codepipeline-introduces-aws-cloudformation-deployment-action/),

> You can now choose AWS CloudFormation as a deployment action in your release workflows built using AWS CodePipeline.

I've worked out most of the Cloudformation Template, but I can't figure out the stages.

```
Resources:
  PipelineRepo:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: pipeline
      RepositoryDescription: Pipeline setup repo

  PipelineArtifacts:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  PipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role

  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: pipeline-pipeline
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location:
          Ref: PipelineArtifacts
      RoleArn:
        Ref: PipelineRole
      Stages:
        ... STAGES ...
```

How do you set up the stages to track CodeCommit and then deploy a CloudFormation template from a file in the repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Offical Documentation:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codepipeline-pipeline-stages-actions.html)

The IAM Role is broken too. Below is a functioning stack. For various types of CF deployments, see the [CF Configuration Properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html#w2ab2c13c13b9). A helpful sample CF stack is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html#w2ab2c13c17b9b8b6).

```
Resources:
  PipelineRepo:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: pipeline
      RepositoryDescription: Pipeline setup repo

  PipelineArtifacts:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  PipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
                - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CloudPipelinePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: "cloudformation:*"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: "codecommit:*"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: "s3:*"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iam:PassRole
                Resource: "*"

  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: pipeline-pipeline
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location:
          Ref: PipelineArtifacts
      RoleArn: !GetAtt [PipelineRole, Arn]
      Stages:
        -
          Name: Source
          Actions:
            -
              Name: CheckoutSourceTemplate
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeCommit
              Configuration:
                PollForSourceChanges: True
                RepositoryName: !GetAtt [PipelineRepo, Name]
                BranchName: master
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: TemplateSource
              RunOrder: 1
        -
          Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            -
              Name: CreateStack
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: 1
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: TemplateSource
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                RoleArn: !GetAtt [PipelineRole, Arn]
                StackName: pipeline
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
                TemplatePath: TemplateSource::template.yml
              RunOrder: 1
```

Comment: Would `${StackConfig}` and `${TemplateFileName}` be paths within the Git repo?

Comment: StackConfig = params file and TemplateFileName = yaml template in the repo. these are passed as parameters.

Comment: `Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]`

Comment: From [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=591290#591290), `you need to add the "--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM" parameter to your command.`